# Extension method on datacontext Linq to sql

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql, generics

Is it possible to create an extension method on the DataContext, not on the table in the datacontext but directly on the dataContext to get dynamicly a table.

ex:

```
DataContext dc = new DataContext();

var test = from a in dc.myExtensionMethod(args) select a;
```

ps: I Already know  `dc.GetTAble` and `dc.GetTable<T>`

Comment: Seems like you are re-inventing the wheel here. Is there a specific reason why you can't use GetTable<T>?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example:

```
namespace System.Data.Linq
{
    public static class DataContextExtensions
    {
        public static bool IsConnected(this DataContext context)
        {
            return (context.Connection.State == ConnectionState.Open);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank, i will give the answer to Chris Arnold, because it's the first one who answer. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It's possible, but since the class is partial, you could simply add your method in a different file

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work:

```
public static IQueryable myExtensionMethod(this DataContext dc)
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what your args is, or if you want to match the signature of GetTable, but...

```
namespace System.Data.Linq
{
    public static class DataContextExtensions
    {
         public static (Table<T>,IQueryable, whatever) 
            MyExtensionMethod(this DataContext context, Args args)
         {
            //do your magic here
         }
    }
}
```